# Python How to get the last word from a sentence in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have below sentence from which i need to get the last word

```
sentence = /name/entry/job/entry/date/
```

i need to get the last word '/date'

```
result= sentence.split()[-1]
print(result)
```

the above code not returning out put

#Expected:
output should return the last word after the split

```
'/date'
```

Request to help on this

Thanks

Comment: ```split()``` splits the string using the ' ' as separator.   You should specify ```split("/")``` assuming that's what the actual separator is.

Comment: @ewong `split()` splits the string using any whitespace character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass "/" as a separator parameter to the split function: `split("/")`.
The split function by default splits by whitespace " ".

```
"Hello World".split() => ["Hello", "World"]
"Hello/World".split() => ["Hello/World"]
"Hello/World".split("/") => ["Hello", "World"]
```

Change your code to:

```
print(sentence.split("/")[-1])
```

Comment: Eduardo , the above code not returning the out put as expected

Comment: @cloud_hari `print(sentence.split("/")[-1])` does that work?

Comment: thanks its working ex expected